# how to use only one listener for multiple sliders (android)?

Tags: java, android, slider

I want to use this [Fluid slider](https://github.com/Ramotion/fluid-slider-android) in my android app and I want 5 of these

if I add different listeners for all 5 then code will become very big. Please take a look and see if multiple sliders can make use of only one setPositionListner method using switch case or any other way.

Below is the code for one fluid slider. First 2 methods is used to hide the text behind and again reveal it and last one is used to find the current position of the slider.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@SuppressWarnings("Convert2Lambda")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    final int max = 45;
    final int min = 10;
    final int total = max - min;

    final FluidSlider slider = findViewById(R.id.fluidSlider);
    slider.setBeginTrackingListener(new Function0<Unit>() {
        @Override
        public Unit invoke() {
            textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return Unit.INSTANCE;
        }
    });

    slider.setEndTrackingListener(new Function0<Unit>() {
        @Override
        public Unit invoke() {
            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return Unit.INSTANCE;
        }
    });

    // Java 8 lambda
    slider.setPositionListener(pos -> {
        final String value = String.valueOf( (int)(min + total * pos) );
        slider.setBubbleText(value);
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
    });


    slider.setPosition(0.3f);
    slider.setStartText(String.valueOf(min));
    slider.setEndText(String.valueOf(max));
}
}
```

Comment: can't understand your requirement

Comment: I want to use 5 sliders in my app but dont want to add individual slider.setPositionListner for each one of them. Like in case of 5 buttons we can use only one onClickListner and use switch case to select action for different buttons